# Почему for in вызывает ошибку, а for работает корректно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, циклы, for

Я пытаюсь оптимизировать мою сборку gulp. У меня в `gulpfile.js` есть функция `fontsStyle`, которая принимает все имена файлов со шрифтами, ну и если такие файлы есть формирует из них `scss` файл, куда подключает эти шрифты. Например, пусть в роли `item` будет `Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf`

Вот фрагмент функции который вызывает проблемы с `for ... in`, но с обычным `for` работает корректно:

```
   for (/*let i = 0 ; i < items.length; ++i*/ let item in items) {
                //let item = items[i];
                item = item.split('.')[0]; // `"Roboto-BoldItalic"`
                let fileName = item; // `"Roboto-BoldItalic"`
                item = item.split('-'); // `["Roboto", "BoldItalic"]`

                let fontname = item[0]; // `"Roboto"` 
                let fontParams = item[1]; // `"BoldItalic"`

                // Тут возникает ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
                fontParams = fontParams.split(/(?!^)(?=[A-Z])/); // а должно быть `["Bold", "Italic"]`
```

На этом этапе я еще не проверяю на `undefined`, но это и не нужно по идее. Меняю цикл обратно на `for` и функция работает. Почему?

Comment: Если вы перебираете массив, замените [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) на [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).  [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) используется для перебора ключей в объекте, для массива он будет просто перебирать номера индексов массива.

Comment: достаточно заменить `let item` на `let i` и раскомментировать строку `//let item = items[i];` и все заработает

Comment: @Grundy Вы не поняли. С обычным for у меня все работает, а с for in нет, я хотел узнать почему именно for in не работает, но мне уже ответили в комментарии выше)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Спасибо, оформите как ответ, я галочку поставлю

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, это ты не понял :) я не говорил раскомментировать простой `for`. `for..in` отлично работает, если сделать изменения указанные в комментарии выше

Comment: @Grundy ага... Извиняюсь тогда. А что быстрее будет работать for in или for of ?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, в зависимости от реализации. В разных браузерах может быть по разному. В последний раз когда проверял `for..of` был медленнее. Сейчас возможно что-то изменилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы перебираете массив, замените [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) на [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) используется для перебора ключей в объекте, для массива он будет просто перебирать номера индексов массива.